# Ceiling fan/light suddenly stopped responding to remote controller

Tags: ceiling-fan

The ceiling fan w/light are controlled by a remote control device. A wall switch which over-rides the remote, i.e., if the wall switch is turned off, the fan and the light would turn off. And, the switch must be turned on for the fan and/or light to respond to the remote.

Suddenly the fan is stuck in low speed, and the light won't turn on. The remote control has power and just to be sure the 9v battery was replaced with a fresh one. The remote has four toggle switches which have not been altered. The receiver is housed at the top of the ceiling fan close to the ceiling. It is about 14 feet from the floor. The receiver dip switches have not been altered either.

What could be done to re-connect the ceiling fan/light and the remote controller

1) Tested the remote control by setting the dip switches to match a remote for an identical and properly functioning ceiling fan in another room. That fan did not respond to the remote.

2) Set the dip switches of the other remote to match the failed remote. The failed fan did not respond to that remote either.

Comment: have you recently replaced any seemingly unrelated lightbulbs?

Comment: Does the fan have pull chains?

Comment: I have had some trouble with the fans with remote controls on two of the new style Hunter fans. One of the fans with remote has worked properly after I removed the receiver for testing (it passed) and reinstalled it. My only guess is depowering the receiver "reset" it. The other fan only works on low setting, but its light works properly (on-off and dimmer both work). I intend to remove the receiver for testing and test the circuitry in the fan by wiring the fan direct and operating it with the pull chains for fan and light.

Comment: When I did the testing on the one fan that now works I removed the receiver and tested it with an incandescent bulb as the load. Since neither the fan nor the light worked I expected it to fail, but it worked!? I reinstalled it and the fan and light worked properly. Then it failed again, but recovered when I turned off the power at the breaker (no wall switch)! It has worked for several years now without another failure. When I check the other fan now working on low only, I will first test in place with my new Fluke VOM to see if I get voltage from the receiver.

Comment: Was the fan installed locally or professionally, if their was reverse polarity it's only a matter of time before the receiver turns into a toy, check the voltage on the receiver and the ohms out of circuit

Comment: The failure can be in the remote (transmitter or receiver) or in the fan circuitry or in the connections of the house wiring to the remote or the remote to the fan. One has to systematically work through it.

Comment: @Jasen, yes - about 2 weeks ago, after one of the three incandescent vanity bulbs failed in one of our guest bathrooms, I replaced all 3 bulbs with 5 watt dimmable led bulbs. The incandescent bulbs I replace were 40 watts dimmable bulbs.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, the fan does not have pull chains.

Comment: @moto, the fan was installed before we moved here, almost six years ago. I'm almost 100% certain the fan was installed by the original homeowner. The house was built in 2003

Comment: remove the LED bulbs and see if the fan works,  it could be the bulbs are broadcasting hash that jams the receiver for your remote control.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the dip switches between the receiver and the remote control somehow became unmatched. The mystery is that it was the receiver that was changed. The receiver is at the ceiling end of the fan. The ceiling is about 15 feet from the floor. Once the receiver dip switches were reset to match the remote dip switches, the issue was resolved.